# Auto search result displayed as cards in angular

Tags: angular

I am about to get the auto populate search using bootstrap in angular.When I try to display the array list in bootstrap card I getting the below error. I am not sure how can I convert the auto populated object to bootstrap cards.

Error:

```
 Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
at DefaultIterableDiffer.diff (core.js:20725)
at NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.js:4483)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:24506)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:35163)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:35102)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:36124)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:36067)
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent.html:116)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:36055)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:35067)
```

Code:

```
<div class="my-0 mr-md-auto font-weight-normal">

<input id="typeahead-template" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model" [ngbTypeahead]="search"
  [resultFormatter]="resultFormatBandListValue" [inputFormatter]="inputFormatBandListValue"
  (focusout)="getList($event)" />

<hr>
<pre>Model: {{ model | json }}</pre>
</div>
<div>
     Dynamically generated
  <div class="container">
  <h5>Bootstrap 4 Equal Height Cards using Grid</h5>
<div *ngIf="IssuesList">
  hello
  {{IssuesList}}
  <div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let issues of IssuesList" class="col-sm-4 py-2">
      <div class="card  text-black ">
        <img class="card-img-top"
          src="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bootstrapbaymisc/blog/24_days_bootstrap/madrid.jpg"
          style="opacity: 0.1;" alt="Madrid">
        <div class="card-body text center">
          <h4 class="card-title">{{issues.issue_name}}</h4>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2">{{issues.issue_number}}</h6>

          <p class="card-text">{{issues.issue_message}}</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read more</a>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
return text$.pipe(      
    debounceTime(200), 
    distinctUntilChanged(),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap( searchText => 
     searchText.length < 2 ? [] : this.IssuesList = this.bugService.GetIssue(searchText).pipe(map(result=>[result]))
  ));
  }

getList($event) {
  this.IssuesList;
}
```

JSON sample:

```
{
   "issue_name": "Bharathi Senthilnath",
   "issue_message": "Banana for seal, red bananna for sale. Address: 10",
   "issue_number": "300 bananna",
   "id": 20
 }
```

After the following code change:

```
 search = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
return text$.pipe(      
    debounceTime(200), 
    distinctUntilChanged(),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap( searchText => 
     searchText.length < 2 ? [] :  
     //this.IssuesList = this.bugService.GetIssue1(searchText).pipe(map(result=>  Object.keys(result).map((key) => [key, result[key]])
     this.IssuesList = this.bugService.GetIssue1(searchText).pipe(map(result=>  Object.keys(result).map((key) => { 
      let newOb = {}; 
      newOb[key] = result[key]; 
      return newOb; 
      })
     ))
  ));
  }
```

UI change

[image]

Comment: which kind of JSON format following your `result`? I mean `map(result=>[result])`

Comment: As I am testing right now. I have converted get method response object to array of result

Comment: how look like your response  JSON?

Comment: Added the response JSON which I will convert it into array of result

Comment: that means your response is following kind of   `[{},{},{}]` JSON format?

Comment: if so please try to use `[...result]` I mean like `.pipe(map(result=>[...result]))`

Comment: bootstrap auto search typeahead accepts only [{},{},{}] and not []

Comment: did you try like `[...result]`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203904/discussion-between-bharathi-and-coder).